# What to do with a Lizardfolk with high Str/Con/Cha?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, ability-scores, lizardfolk

Brief explanation; this is my third/fourth character of the campaign (after 4 sessions). He was originally a level 2 Elf Ranger, but after a mishap with a trapped temple and a Cloaker he got reincarnated as a level 1 Lizardfolk ranger. (My previous chars were a delightfully fun Warforged who was just about to kick ass as an incarnate/swordsage hybrid but got critical'ed by an ogre wielding a greatclub, and a short-lived half-orc sorcerer who fell down a well shaft and... folded in half, kinda.)

First things first: stats.

> STR: 15. DEX: 9. CON: 17. INT: 7. WIS: 11. CHA: 15.

So, not that bad. I sunk a feat into Point Blank Shot because the original Elf Ranger was going to be an archer, and I can't change that. The natural armour bonus of +1 at the low level is fun, and having two claw and one bite attack is new. My question is, what are some good options? A paladin relies on the exact stats I have in abundance, a barbarian would fit nicely with raging claw/bite attacks, continuing as a ranger focused on Two-Weapon(claw) fighting is also an option... but none of these are classes I've really experienced, hence the question. As far as character goal goes; nothing specific per se, but high damage would be nice. I've heard there's various ways to get magic enchants on my claws... Also, DM house rules state that since I had a character previously in Incarnate, I can't go that route until my next character. Same for Swordsage and Sorcerer. Totemist could be good, but the DM is reviewing that until he determines whether it's 'broken' (he saw Blink Shirt and nixed it immediately).

Edit: I've pretty much decided to go for a Ranger/Paladin hybrid. My DM has declared that both those class levels shall stack for the purposes of a Druid's animal companion, which I can take instead of a special mount/Ranger animal companion. With the Natural Bond feat I'd have full access to all the good companions (huge viper at level 7? Yes please!). Now my main concern is making the most of my high Strength score (since the high Charisma will be used by Paladin spells) to do some damage. What stuff exists to buff natural attacks with claws/bite attacks?

Comment: Stop, sit down with your DM, and discuss all the things going horribly wrong in this campaign. The turn-over rate you’re describing is *insane*, and your lack of ready-to-go characters indicates it wasn’t explicitly stated up-front that it would be. The enormous level gap is **terrible** in this system, and should be eliminated. I don’t know if it was his call or yours to use *reincarnate*, but if it was his or he forced you to use it, that may be a problem too, since you’re now a random character that wasn’t your choice. In short, your DM has a lot to learn about running the game.

Comment: @kyran I... suspect that level gap is because lizardman is a preposterous 2 HD +1 LA.

Comment: I recommend turning your edit into a different, much smaller, question. You may also want to reference the devoted tracker feat, since I assume that's what you took (or were granted) as your first hd feat.

Answer (score 3):

In your *very* brief tour, I'd recommend dipping into [*Binder*](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=2942.0).

Your game is unique and seems to have an extremely high character turnover. Therefore, take the opportunity to explore new mechanical subsystems, and binder has been my favourite for quite a long time. You can be flexible in what stats you use, and point blank shot has quite a lot of utility in some of the builds.

Therefore, take this brief walk across the stage as a binder, and enjoy the novelty.

Beyond that, the binder is a decent class for being sneaky and talky. You're facing a 4 level discrepancy, and the binder offers you the ability to be alternatively useful, other than in frontline melee combat. While you have strength and con, you have *no* hit points worth speaking of. Play with binder, as you can start out with a "stand-off" build designed to carry you through a few levels as well as social situations, and then you can explore a renewed melee focus with a daily choice.

You're a lizardfolk with a +1 level adjustment and 2 HD. The first thing to do is to investigate if you're allowed to buy off [level adjustments](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/reducingLevelAdjustments.htm). As a level 3 or 4 ranger, it will be a while before you level up. Looking at the natural weapons [mini guide](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=10994.0) ... we come out with the impression that two weapon fighting is [kind of nice](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?279079-3-5-The-TWF-OffHandbook).

As a lizardman/2 ranger/1 binder/1, you're not really in the best spot feat-wise. At all. One of the first feats binders need is improved binding. You'll want to grab two-weapon fighting as your "free" feat from your lizardman HD. When you take binder/1, your default bind will be Amon (until you can get improved binding) or Naberius, depending if it's combat heavy or not. Amon gives you horns and a quite nice charge attack, as well as a Horns, Bite, Claw, Claw combo which is not to be sneezed at.

As you level up, you'll gain access to Savnok and Malphas, which will greatly increase your longevity. If you survive more than 3 levels, you'll then have a chance to invest in directions that are useful to the character.

Comment: Actually, the other two players are still with their original characters (at level 4). I'm the only one dying (not on purpose either, I just get unlucky with dice rolls), so here I am at lvl1 with 0xp.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan That’s not bad luck, that’s bad DMing. As soon as you died once, you were basically doomed to continue to endlessly repeat the cycle of deaths because of the level loss. I see no way out of it other than sitting down with your DM and convincing him that this policy he has is a **big** mistake.

Comment: It's not that bad, I'll level up quickly if I stay out of the way and don't die for a 4/5th time. This DM's policies are non-negotiable anyway, and I wouldn't want to argue with him on that. The rolling-stats-after-class is weird, but a challenge. Usually new chars enter 2 levels below the rest of the party but this was a specific situation I was in.

Answer (score 1):

**A fangshields ranger will give you multiattack for free, saving a critical feat, and full ranger progression with a few dips can serve you well enough.**

Presuming that your DM allows retraining (as per DMG2) ranger is not actually a bad fit for a lizardman.

Look for the Fangshields ranger (champions of valor) for its level 2 substitution level which gives you multiattack for free. Your third class level should be a Spirit Lion Totem Barbarian (Complete Champion) for pounce. I'm neatly skirting around suggesting Totemist here, as that seems to be contraindicated by your DM for... reasons. (The blink shirt being able to teleport at level one isn't a useful reason, as most spellcasting classes can do this if they put some effort into it.)

This strategy is basically "charge the enemy, hope you kill them."